# Textarea line break no working properly

Tags: php, sql, .htaccess, str-replace, fwrite

I have a best problem in my experience, I want to write .htaccess file by fwrite(), when it debug its show ok in side the textarea but when I going to submit that then it show \n\r\n\r.... I was try str_replace() and its work but that does not break line. This is my all codes, please help me.

> submit.php

```
<?php

//.htaccess file write and rewrite query

$file = ".htaccess";

$submit7 = $_POST['submit7'];

$edit = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace( array("\r\n", "\n"), " ", $_POST['edit']));




function wee() {

    echo "<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> \n
\n RewriteEngine on \n";

    require('config2.php'); $getquery=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY menu_id DESC"); while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery)){$menu_id=$rows['menu_id']; $linkname=$rows['linkname'];

echo "\n RewriteRule ^".$linkname."/{0,1}$  pagee.php?menu_id=".$menu_id. "[QSA,L] \n"; }

    echo "\n </IfModule>";



} 




    if ($submit7) {
    if ( is_writable( $file ) ) {
        // is_writable() not always reliable, check return value. see comments @ http://uk.php.net/is_writable
        $f = fopen( $file, 'w+');
        if ( $f !== false ) {
            fwrite( $f, $edit );
            fclose( $f );

        }
    }
}



?>





<form id="form7" name="form7" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
      <label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit7" value="Write" />
      </label>

<textarea name="edit"><?php echo wee(); ?></textarea>



    </form>
```

> config2.php

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("myweb");


?>


<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','')
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("myweb");
?>
```

> sql.sql

```
--
-- Database: `myweb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `menu`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menu` (
  `menu_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mname` text NOT NULL,
  `level` text NOT NULL,
  `linkname` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `menu`
--

INSERT INTO `menu` (`menu_id`, `mname`, `level`, `linkname`) VALUES
(1, 'Home', 'home', 'aaaa'),
(2, 'Music', 'Music', 'Music'),
(3, 'Movie', 'Movie', 'Movie'),
(4, 'Song', 'Song', 'Song');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `menu`
--
ALTER TABLE `menu`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`menu_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `menu`
--
ALTER TABLE `menu`
  MODIFY `menu_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=5;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

> .htaccess --- output result now showing

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  RewriteEngine on  RewriteRule ^Song/{0,1}$  pagee.php?menu_id=4[QSA,L]  RewriteRule ^Movie/{0,1}$  pagee.php?menu_id=3[QSA,L]  RewriteRule ^Music/{0,1}$  pagee.php?menu_id=2[QSA,L]  RewriteRule ^aaaa/{0,1}$  pagee.php?menu_id=1[QSA,L]  </IfModule>
```

> But I want that like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  

RewriteEngine on  

RewriteRule ^Song/{0,1}$  pagee.php?menu_id=4[QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^Movie/{0,1}$  pagee.php?menu_id=3[QSA,L]  
RewriteRule ^Music/{0,1}$  pagee.php?menu_id=2[QSA,L]  
RewriteRule ^aaaa/{0,1}$  pagee.php?menu_id=1[QSA,L]  

</IfModule>
```

Please Please Please HELP ME......

Comment: Maybe a clue to your problem. It's OS specific. Linux use "\n" as a line break while Windows use "\r\n". When I had similar problems, I had to convert the line breaks according to the server OS.

Comment: Have u tried PHP_EOL instead ?

Comment: @GeorgiosDimitriadis: Thank you, I am using windows OS but my problem is not solve yet....

Comment: @Falt4rm: YES SIR; It same as like as /n/r/n/r/n/r/n/r/n/r  ...........

Comment: @Falt4rm when I submit with textarea then that problem come

Comment: try using the php function nl2br

Comment: Think i have an idea xD. $edit is cleaned by str_replace \r\n . Try echoing the $edit - U should have the solution

Comment: @DCR OK SIR I going to that too

Comment: @Falt4rm echo where textarea????

Comment: The textarea in submit.php is filled by wee() function right ? - then u take $_POST['edit'] and replace "/n/r" by " " right ? That would explain Why u don't have any /r/n in the destination file

Comment: @DCR : NOT WORKING IT SHOW THAT ( &lt;IfModule mod_rewrite.c&gt; <br />\r\n<br />\r\n<br />\r\n RewriteEngine on <br />\r\n<br />\r\n<br />\r\n<br />\r\n<br />\r\n<br />\r\n<br />\r\n<br />\r\n<br />\r\n RewriteRule ^Song/{0,1}$  pagee.php?menu_id=4[QSA,L] <br />\r\n<br />\r\n RewriteRule ^Movie/{0,1}$  pagee.php?menu_id=3[QSA,L] <br />\r\n<br />\r\n RewriteRule ^Music/{0,1}$  pagee.php?menu_id=2[QSA,L] <br />\r\n<br />\r\n RewriteRule ^aaaa/{0,1}$  pagee.php?menu_id=1[QSA,L] <br />\r\n<br />\r\n &lt;/IfModule&gt; )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Dear I think I find you result just do that replacement ok,

> submit.php

```
<?php
//.htaccess file write and rewrite query

$file = ".htaccess";
$submit7 = $_POST['submit7'];

if ($submit7) 
{
   $htfe = file_put_contents('.htaccess', $_POST['edit']);
}

function wee() 
{
    echo "<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> \n
    \n RewriteEngine on \n";
    require('config2.php'); $getquery=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY menu_id DESC"); while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery)){$menu_id=$rows['menu_id']; $linkname=$rows['linkname'];
    echo "\n RewriteRule ^".$linkname."/{0,1}$  pagee.php?menu_id=".$menu_id. "[QSA,L] \n"; }
    echo "\n </IfModule>";
}
?>

<form id="form7" name="form7" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
      <label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit7" value="Write" />
      </label>
      <textarea name="edit"><?php echo wee(); ?></textarea>
</form>
```

I thing you should get you solution, ok
Just change this file `submit.php` ok

Answer (score 3):

**Four solutions:**

**1)** Use PHP function [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

**e.g.**

```
echo nl2br("This\r\nis\n\ra\nstring\r");

// will output
This<br />
is<br />
a<br />
string<br />
```

---

**2)** Wrap the input in `<pre></pre>` tag.

**See:** http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/pre

---

**3)** Use,

```
$textToStore = nl2br(htmlentities($inputText, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

---

**4)** Use,

```
file_put_contents('.htaccess', $_POST['textarea_value']);
```

`file_put_contents()` combines the functions of `fopen`, `fwrite`, `fclose`

Comment: This is my output inside my file   ( &lt;IfModule mod_rewrite.c&gt; <br />\r\n<br />\r\n<br />\r\n RewriteEngine on <br />\r\n<br />\r\n<br />\r\n<br />\r\n<br />\r\n<br />\r\n<br />\r\n<br />\r\n<br />\r\n RewriteRule ^Song/{0,1}$  pagee.php?menu_id=4[QSA,L] <br />\r\n<br />\r\n RewriteRule ^Movie/{0,1}$  pagee.php?menu_id=3[QSA,L] <br />\r\n<br />\r\n RewriteRule ^Music/{0,1}$  pagee.php?menu_id=2[QSA,L] <br />\r\n<br />\r\n RewriteRule ^aaaa/{0,1}$  pagee.php?menu_id=1[QSA,L] <br />\r\n<br />\r\n &lt;/IfModule&gt; )

Comment: Try using the 4th solution.

Comment: OK Sir I will do that too

Comment: Remove all file open or writing functions and just use `file_put_contents` to write contents to the file.

Comment: OK Sir I will do that also wait.